# Java: mThread = null прерывает поток?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть поток:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {...});
```

В нём есть бесконечный цикл `while (true)`. Если я через некоторое время после запуска потока

```
t.start();
```

выполню этот код

```
t = null;
```

то мой бесконечный цикл внутри этого потока будет остановлен?

Comment: Не знаю, скорее вылетит `NullPointerException`

Comment: @СергейГрушин, где? В цикле или в коде, где я написал `t = null`?

Comment: В цикле. Ну это имхо. По сути, поток теряет инициализацию. А значит и все циклы и прочие гадости будут уничтожены. хотя стоп. мне кажется остановится

Comment: А почему вдруг то, что вы потеряли ссылку на поток, должно его немедленно остановить? Ведь телевизор у вас дома не исчезает, если вы на него не смотрите.

Comment: @VladD, я не понимаю о чём вы. я уже решил вопрос.

Comment: @L'Esperanza: Я о том, что если бы вы немного лучше понимали, что такое ссылка в Java (на любой объект, не обязательно на Thread), то вопрос не мог бы возникнуть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Остановить цикл и, соответственно, сам поток может только метод `stop()`

```
t.stop();
```

Вот это

```
t = null;
```

или

```
t.interrupt();
```

не приведёт ни к чему. Проверил только что сам.

Comment: однгвременно проверили))

Comment: Метод `stop()` deprecated и нерекомендован к использованию. Чтобы сработал `interrupt()` ваш поток должен находиться в состоянии прерываемого ожидания. Читайте javadoc. Метод тыка дает неправильное представление о вещах.

Comment: @a_gura, к сожалению, я не могу сделать поток в режиме ожидания. Там используется `Socket.connect(...)` с таймаутом в секундах, и также указано время ожидания входящего потока. Javadoc я читал, из полезного нашёл только метод `stop()`. О каком методе тыка вы имеете ввиду? Я отвечал не на авось и не бездумно.

Answer (score 1):

Собрал тестовое приложение, где при старте создается поток и запускается, а кнопкой `back` становится `null`. Итог: ничего не вылетает, а цикл продолжает свою работу.

Comment: совершенно верно. Уже протестировал сам. Спасибо.